# How to use colon operator to reverse the order of vector

Tags: r

How to use colon operator to reverse the order of vector in R. I have tried sorting the vector again, but that is not right.

Comment: Can you give an example of the vector and what you'd like to do?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the colon operator to reverse the order of a vector and show that it is the same as sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)

Comment: Both `4:1` and `sort(1:4, decreasing=TRUE)` do what I expect. Furthermore, `vec <- c(11,12,13,14); vec[4:1];` works too.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to somehow use the colon operator to reverse a vector, then I would do:

```
vec[length(vec):1]
```

`length(vec):1` generates a sequence running from `length(vec)` down to 1 (e.g. `50, 49, 48, ..., 3, 2, 1`, which is used to index `vec`.

Example:

```
vec = rpois(34, 5)
vec
 [1]  3 12  8  5  4  3  8  4  4  3  2 11  6  7  2  6  6  5  4  3
  4  4  7  7  2  7  5  7  5  9  7  4  3  5
vec[length(vec):1]
 [1]  5  3  4  7  9  5  7  5  7  2  7  7  4  4  3  4  5  6  6  2  
  7  6 11  2  3  4  4  8  3  4  5  8 12  3
all(vec[length(vec):1] == rev(vec))
[1] TRUE
```

As shown in the example, there is already a function `rev()` built into R that does this, and is probably a better option in most cases.